# Copy next line after nth match - Python

Tags: python, match

I want to append the lines after the 3rd match of "config vdom" string. Unfortunately the script only consider the 1st match.

Original code:

```
x = list()

def z():
with open('test.conf', 'r') as rf:
    for line in rf:
        if 'config vdom\n' in line:
            while True:
                line = (rf.__next__())
                if 'end\n' in line:
                    break
                x.append(line)
            with open('test.txt', 'w') as wf:
                wf.writelines(x)
            return
```

I'm planning to used the enumerate but doesn't sure how to apply it in adding the next line.

Enumerate line:

```
z = [i for i, n in enumerate(y) if n == 'config vdom\n'][2]
print('Line', z, ':', y[z])
```

**Output:**

```
Line 10310 : config vdom
```

Sample Data:

```
config vdom
config system global
    set admin-maintainer disable
    set admin-scp enable
 end
config vdom*
config system accprofile
    edit "prof_admin"
        set admingrp read-write
        set utmgrp read-write
        set vpngrp read-write
        set wanoptgrp read-write
        set wifi read-write
config vdom*
test sample data
end
```

expected Output: It should be the three line below will be added in the x list.

```
config vdom*
test sample data
end
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: Add the sample now.

Comment: Expected output `test sample data` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help.

```
with open('test.txt', 'a') as wf:
    with open('test.conf', 'r') as rf:
        c = 0                 #Checkvalue
        for line in rf:
            if 'config vdom\n' in line:
                c += 1
                if c == 3:      #Check if 3rd "config vdom"
                    while True:
                        line = next(rf)
                        if 'end\n' in line:
                            break
                        wf.writelines(line)      #Write required content.
```

Answer (score 0):

[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20groupby#itertools.groupby) could help:

```
from itertools import groupby
from io import StringIO

text = '''config vdom
config system global
    set admin-maintainer disable
    set admin-scp enable
 end
config vdom*
config system accprofile
    edit "prof_admin"
        set admingrp read-write
        set utmgrp read-write
        set vpngrp read-write
        set wanoptgrp read-write
        set wifi read-write
config vdom*
test sample data
end'''

count = 0
with StringIO(text) as file:
    for key, group in groupby(file, key=lambda x: 'config vdom' in x):
        if key is True:
            count += 1
        if count == 3 and key is False:
            with StringIO() as out_file:
                out_file.writelines(group)
                print(out_file.getvalue())
```

this prints (or writes to your file)

```
test sample data
end
```

...is that your desired output?

`key` will be `True` for every line where `'config vdom'` appears and false for all other lines. `group` collects all the lines until the value of `key` changes.

you'd need to replace all the `StringIO` parts with your desired files.